# Matplotlib plot fails, but scatter succeeds with same data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, python-datetime

I'm trying to produce a plot of various pandas series using matplotlib.

This works fine: `plt.scatter(ahi_m['Time'], ahi_m['Min'])`

But this causes an error: `plt.plot(ahi_m['Time'], ahi_m['Min'])`

Here's the error from `plt.plot`:

```
    343     dt = (np.datetime64(get_epoch()) +
--> 344           np.timedelta64(int(np.round(x * MUSECONDS_PER_DAY)), 'us'))
    345     if dt < np.datetime64('0001-01-01') or dt >= np.datetime64('10000-01-01'):
    346         raise ValueError(f'Date ordinal {x} converts to {dt} (using '
OverflowError: int too big to convert
```

I don't understand why `plot` fails while `scatter` succeeds. Both the x and y variables are pandas Series. `ahi_m['Time']` has dtype `datetime64[ns]` while `ahi_m['Min']` has dtype `float64`.

Any ideas what's going on here and, more importantly, how to solve it? I presume it's something to do with the datetime variable being in `ns` and thus being a very large number. Can I convert it somehow?

(edit) Update: If I convert `ahi_m['Time']` into a numpy array then it works:
`plt.plot(np.array(ahi_m['Time']), np.array(ahi_m['Min']))`

But it would still be good to know why. Is this a pandas or matplotlib bug?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get the same error when you reduce the number of rows for plotting?

Comment: Yes, this happens no matter how many rows there are.

Comment: Can you then add a minimal example of your dataframe to reproduce the problem?